# jQuery plugin - How to pass a parameter

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have this plugin that should receive an integer as a parameter

```
('foo').myplugin(3);
```

How do I pass the parameter to the plugin function?

I have tried something like this -

```
$.fn.myplugin = function(int){
alert(int);  
}   //suppose to alert "3"
```

yet, it doesn't seem to work

Comment: `$('foo').myplugin(3);` missing `$`

Comment: Remember javascript is a loose type.

Comment: `('foo')` what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `$` at the start of your statement:

```
$('foo').myplugin(3);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NxP4p/